# Basic Python data validation

Tags: python, validation

So I'm doing my GSCE's and our task was to create a simple, text-based game. I tried to add some data validation to show my teacher that I can do it but it turns out... I can't do it... It will likely seem really easy to anybody who is remotely good at Python but for some reason when I run the program it has an "invalid syntax", so I fixed that issue (by simply adding a ":") but then it says the indentation is wrong? The data validation is near the beginning where you are given the choice to go "left" or "right"; I want it to give you the question again if you type anything other than "left" or "right"... Please somebody help! (Also please ignore the rubbish story).

```
import time
import sys

print("Mars: 2040. The human race has been wiped out of existence by the alien race. Will you suffer the same fate?")
time.sleep(3)
name=input("What is your name?")

def start()
    print("Okay",name,", which direction would you like to go? Left or right?")
    direction=input()

    if direction == "left":
        print("You turn the corner to discover a large, wolf-life monster. It erupts in deafening roar and proceeds towards you.")
            print("You enter the room and see a bow (and arrow) on the ground next to a sword. Which do you take? *Bow* or *sword*?")
            weapon=input()

            if weapon == "bow":
                print("You fire the arrow into one of the eyes of the large monster. It stumbles, but stays on it's feet")
                print("Nice hit! What now? *Shoot again* or *reach for your pocket*?")
                weapon2=input()

                if weapon2 == "shoot again":
                      print("You pull back the string and release. It soars over the head of the monster. The monster raises it's leg and stamps on your puny head.")
                      time.sleep(3)
                      print("GAME OVER")
                      exit()

                if weapon2 == "reach for your pocket":
                        print("You pull out a sharp knife and throw it towards the monster. it strikes the leg of the monster and it crumbles to the ground. You run over, grabbing th eknife as you do and stab the monster in it's red, glowing eye. You win!")
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print("Congratulations! You win!!1! :D")
                        print("Game created by Tom Jolley.")

            elif weapon == "sword":
                print("You take a large, over-exaggerated swing... the sword falls to the ground with a loud bang as you dropped it 1 foot away from you because it was ''too heavy''... the monster stares at you you for a moment and it stamps on your head.")
                time.sleep(5)
                print("GAME OVER")
                exit()

    elif direction == "right":
            print("You turn the corner to discover a ginormous arachnid drooling and staring at you with it's 8 glowing red eyes. It proceeds towards you.")
            print("...well no, that's not a direction... just stand there..")
            print("You enter the room and see a bow (and arrow) on the ground next to a sword. Which do you take? *Bow* or *sword*?")
            weapon=input()

            if weapon == "bow":
                print("You fire the arrow into one of the eyes of the large monster. It stumbles, but stays on it's feet")
                print("Nice hit! What now? *Shoot again* or *reach for your pocket*?")
                weapon2=input()

                if weapon2 == "shoot again":
                      print("You pull back the string and release. It soars over the head of the monster. The monster raises it's leg and stamps on your puny head.")
                      time.sleep(3)
                      print("GAME OVER")
                      exit()

                if weapon2 == "reach for your pocket":
                        print("You pull out a sharp knife and throw it towards the monster. it strikes the leg of the monster and it crumbles to the ground. You run over, grabbing th eknife as you do and stab the monster in it's red, glowing eye. You win!")
                        time.sleep(4)
                        print("Congratulations! You win!!1! :D")
                        print("Game created by Tom Jolley.")

            elif weapon == "sword":
                print("You take a large, over-exaggerated swing... the sword falls to the ground with a loud bang as you dropped it 1 foot away from you because it was ''too heavy''... the monster stares at you you for a moment and it stamps on your head.")
                time.sleep(5)
                print("GAME OVER")
                exit()


    else:
        print()
        start()

start()
```

Comment: Line 12 `print` is indented too much (and every `if` block within that. Some of your other indents are more than 4 spaces (`if weapon2 == "shoot again"` for instance

Comment: You need to use incremental programming (especially if you are a beginner). Don't just write 50-100 lines of code without even checking if it will *compile*, at least try to run bits and pieces first.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly a spacing issue here, there's a lot of 8 spaces instead of 4 and some places where it's 5

```
import time
import sys

print("Mars: 2040. The human race has been wiped out of existence by the alien race. Will you suffer the same fate?")
time.sleep(3)
name=input("What is your name?")

def start()
    print("Okay",name,", which direction would you like to go? Left or right?")
    direction=input()

    if direction == "left":
        print("You turn the corner to discover a large, wolf-life monster. It erupts in deafening roar and proceeds towards you.")
        print("You enter the room and see a bow (and arrow) on the ground next to a sword. Which do you take? *Bow* or *sword*?")
        weapon=input()

        if weapon == "bow":
            print("You fire the arrow into one of the eyes of the large monster. It stumbles, but stays on it's feet")
            print("Nice hit! What now? *Shoot again* or *reach for your pocket*?")
                weapon2=input()

            if weapon2 == "shoot again":
                 print("You pull back the string and release. It soars over the head of the monster. The monster raises it's leg and stamps on your puny head.")
                 time.sleep(3)
                 print("GAME OVER")
                 exit()

            if weapon2 == "reach for your pocket":
                print("You pull out a sharp knife and throw it towards the monster. it strikes the leg of the monster and it crumbles to the ground. You run over, grabbing th eknife as you do and stab the monster in it's red, glowing eye. You win!")
                time.sleep(4)
                print("Congratulations! You win!!1! :D")
                print("Game created by Tom Jolley.")

        elif weapon == "sword":
            print("You take a large, over-exaggerated swing... the sword falls to the ground with a loud bang as you dropped it 1 foot away from you because it was ''too heavy''... the monster stares at you you for a moment and it stamps on your head.")
            time.sleep(5)
            print("GAME OVER")
            exit()

    elif direction == "right":
        print("You turn the corner to discover a ginormous arachnid drooling and staring at you with it's 8 glowing red eyes. It proceeds towards you.")
        print("...well no, that's not a direction... just stand there..")
        print("You enter the room and see a bow (and arrow) on the ground next to a sword. Which do you take? *Bow* or *sword*?")
        weapon=input()

        if weapon == "bow":
            print("You fire the arrow into one of the eyes of the large monster. It stumbles, but stays on it's feet")
            print("Nice hit! What now? *Shoot again* or *reach for your pocket*?")
            weapon2=input()

            if weapon2 == "shoot again":
                print("You pull back the string and release. It soars over the head of the monster. The monster raises it's leg and stamps on your puny head.")
                time.sleep(3)
                print("GAME OVER")
                exit()

            if weapon2 == "reach for your pocket":
                print("You pull out a sharp knife and throw it towards the monster. it strikes the leg of the monster and it crumbles to the ground. You run over, grabbing th eknife as you do and stab the monster in it's red, glowing eye. You win!")
                time.sleep(4)
                print("Congratulations! You win!!1! :D")
                print("Game created by Tom Jolley.")

        elif weapon == "sword":
            print("You take a large, over-exaggerated swing... the sword falls to the ground with a loud bang as you dropped it 1 foot away from you because it was ''too heavy''... the monster stares at you you for a moment and it stamps on your head.")
            time.sleep(5)
            print("GAME OVER")
            exit()


    else:
        print()
        start()

start()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python indentation (the whitespace at the start of a line) makes a big difference. These two blocks of code look very similar, but don't do the same thing

```
for x in xs:
    if x == "foo":
        good()
    else:
        bad()
```

vs

```
for x in xs:
    if x == "foo":
        good()
else:
    bad()
```

---

To answer your question, look at the code on line 14. To make it clear I've replaced spaces (' ') with '>' on that line

```
if direction == "left":
        print("You turn the corner to discover a large, wolf-life monster. It erupts in deafening roar and proceeds towards you.")
>>>>>>>>>>>>print("You enter the room and see a bow (and arrow) on the ground next to a sword. Which do you take? *Bow* or *sword*?")
            weapon=input()

            if weapon == "bow":
                print...
```

Notice how it has a different amount of spaces to the line above it? That should never really happen unless you are inside a block. You'll know for sure you are inside a block if the previous line ended with a colon ':'.

To fix the code, make sure everything inside the same block has the same amount of indentation. I would change your code to look something like

```
if direction == "left":
    print("You turn the corner to discover a large, wolf-life monster. It erupts in deafening roar and proceeds towards you.")
    print("You enter the room and see a bow (and arrow) on the ground next to a sword. Which do you take? *Bow* or *sword*?")
    weapon=input()

    if weapon == "bow":
        print...
```

---

For reference, here are some samples of correctly indented pieces of code. Notice how in the last example, only one space is used instead of four. The exact number of spaces doesn't matter, once it is the same for each line inside the block.

```
for line in textfile:
    process(line)

i = 0
while i < 5:
    i += 1
    print(i)

with open("testresults.csv", 'r') as f:
    results = f.readlines()
    if good(results):
        print("Yay!")
    else:
        print("Aww")

i = 0
while i < 5:
 i += 1
 print(i)
```